# rewrite .htaccess https all but one folder

Tags: css, .htaccess, http

I am looking for a way to add https to all my website but one folder and all its files

the folder is sitename.com/shop
when i put on htpps for all folder the shop don't work right

is there a way i can do this in .htaccess i am using 
open-eshop.com product i try with the full https for the entire site  but it don't seem to work with https 
Thank you 
i did this but still didn't work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(login|/support|/community/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: it is don't work with https, because by default apache setup way that ignore .htaccess for https.

Comment: is there a way to change the default Apache or override it

Comment: sure - if you have access to apache files (usually httpd.conf, but some times virtualhost settings by domains can be in separate files). In this case you can allow using .htaccess for ssl (AllowOverride All), or what is better  - add rules directly into virtualhost settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to apache files (usually httpd.conf, but some times virtualhost settings by domains can be in separate files). In this case you can allow using .htaccess for ssl (AllowOverride All), or what is better - add rules directly into virtualhost settings.

Based on what you told,  i think you already have some rules for redirect index.php in you apache configs.